# Subtracting two nested list of arrays using a for loop in R

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop

I have a long list of nested arrays (60 elements long) and I'd like to subtract another nested list of arrays (also 60 elements long). The issue here is that elements in the first list have different dimensions than the second. Here's a condensed/simplified example. I have lists similar to `example1` and `example2` but mine are all different (non-repetitive) numbers:

```
#create example1
set.seed(1)
example1.1 <- list(array(rnorm(18), dim = c(6,3, 10)))
example1.2 <- list(array(rnorm(12), dim = c(4,3, 10)))
example1 <- list(example1.1, example1.2)

#create example2
set.seed(2)
example2.1 <- list(array(rnorm(18), dim = c(6,3, 1)))
example2.2 <- list(array(rnorm(12), dim = c(4,3, 1)))
example2 <- list(example2.1, example2.2)
```

Basically, I'd like to subtract example2.1 from example1.1 at each of it's different height positions, and then example2.2 from example1.2. It would be great if the output was also a list of arrays like:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
, , 1

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 2

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 3

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 4

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 5

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 6

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 7

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 8

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 9

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

, , 10

            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  0.27046074 -0.2205257 -0.2285452
[2,] -0.00120586  0.9780227 -1.1750309
[3,] -2.42347394 -1.4086926 -0.6572980
[4,]  2.72565648 -0.1666014  2.2661355
[5,]  0.40975953  1.0941304 -0.8947948
[6,] -0.95288867 -0.5919095  0.9080295

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
, , 1

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 3

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 4

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 5

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 6

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 7

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 8

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 9

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653

, , 10

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.6392825 -1.2601304 0.09854405
[2,] -0.2486218 -2.7751200 0.29116978
[3,] -2.9264478  0.4824913 0.71957790
[4,]  2.7952066  3.1900311 0.10020653
```

I suspect I simply don't know how to subset the loop appropriately. Any help anyone can give is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by *"at each of it's different height positions,"*?  What *height* are you  reffering to?

Comment: Hi, Dario. I'd like to subtract the elements of ```example2``` from the elements of ```example1``` at position [,,i]. I hope that makes sense. So, basically subtract ```example2``` from those 10 elements.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean... It sounds like you want to subtract a 4 x 3 matrix from a 6x4 matrix... But as you realized, there is no standard way to subtract a n*m matrix from a o*p matrix... What is the expected output ? Also, if this is correct, I'd suggest getting rid of the nested array and focus on the matrix subtraction (1 problem at a time). Best of luck!

Comment: I'd like to substract the 6x3 array represented by ```example2.1``` from all height positions [,,i] from the 6x3 arrays represented by ```example1.1```. I'd like also like to do the same for the 4x3 arrays represented by ```example2.2``` and ```example1.2```. However, my lists are in the form of ```example1``` and ```example2```. I just can't figure out how to appropriately point to these different areas in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this ? :

```
Results.1 <- list(array(NA, dim = c(6,3,10)))
for(i in 1:10){
  Results.1[[1]][,,i] <- example1.1[[1]][,,i]-example2.1[[1]][,,1]
}
```

For the example1 list :

```
Results[[1]] = list(array(NA, dim = c(6,3, 10)))
Results[[2]] = list(array(NA, dim = c(4,3, 10)))
for(i in 1:length(example1)){
   for(j in 1:10){
     Results[[i]][[1]][,,j] <- example1[[i]][[1]][,,j]-example2[[i]][[1]][,,1]
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this! My data is in the form of ```example1``` and ```example2```. Can you think of anyway to create a loop that outputs [[1]][[1]] (which you did!) and [[2]][[1]]?

Comment: I'm asking this because my actual data goes up to [[60]], and I really don't want to copy/paste the same code 60 times (especially since I plan on sharing the code with others).

Comment: I am not sure to understand I'm sorry. What do you mean by [[1]][[2]] and [[2]][[1]] ?

Comment: My apologies, Maxime. There was a typo in my original comment. In the suggested output there are two parts. The first [[1]][[1]] you calculated (thank you again!), but the second part [[2]][[1]] consists of the 4x3 arrays. Can you think of a loop that will include that in the output as well?

Comment: if you add this `Results.2[[1]][,,i] <- example1.2[[1]][,,i]-example2.2[[1]][,,1}`in the loop it doesn't work ?

Comment: That loop absolutely works for that part of the data! But I'm hoping to create one list from my data (in reality it is 60 elements long). I just don't think it's a good idea to separate the longer list I have into 60 different objects and then copy/paste the same code 60 times.

Comment: If you change `1:10` by `1:60` is that what you mean maybe ?

Comment: Perhaps this is the problem? So, for this example it would be 1:20. How would that look only using ```example1``` and ```example2``` in a loop? Sorry we can't move this to a chat.

Comment: I think you can adapt this `Results[[1]] = list(array(NA, dim = c(6,3, 10)))
Results[[2]] = list(array(NA, dim = c(4,3, 10)))
for(i in 1:length(example1)){
  for(j in 1:10){
    Results[[i]][[1]][,,j] <- example1[[i]][[1]][,,j]-example2[[i]][[1]][,,1]  
  }
}`

Comment: This works! Thank you so much, Maxime! I'll mark it answered if you want to add another answer with this code (want to make sure you get credit if you want):
Results <- list()
Results[[1]] <-  list(array(NA, dim = c(6,3, 10))) 
Results[[2]] <- list(array(NA, dim = c(4,3, 10))) 
for(i in 1:length(example1)){
  for(j in 1:10){
    Results[[i]][[1]][,,j] <- example1[[i]][[1]][,,j]-example2[[i]][[1]][,,1]
  }
  }